# MSVC: why "#pragma fenv_access (on)" causes "error C2099: initializer is not a constant"?

Tags: c, visual-c++, floating-point, initialization, cl

Sample code (t50.c):

```
#pragma fenv_access (on)
float d = 0.0 + 0.0;
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Invocation:

```
$ cl t50.c /fp:strict
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.25.28611 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

t50.c
t50.c(2): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

Question: why `#pragma fenv_access (on)` causes `error C2099: initializer is not a constant`? What is the reason / motivation?

Is it because on `#pragma fenv_access (on)` `cl` is not allowed to perform constant folding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/fenv-access?view=msvc-160):

> The compiler disables floating-point optimizations, so your code can access the floating-point environment consistently.
> ...
> The kinds of optimizations that are subject to fenv_access are:
>
> - Global common subexpression elimination
> - Code motion
> - Constant folding

Treating `1.0 + 1.0` as a constant is an example of constant folding.

Although the language specifies that this is a constant expression, so it can be used as a static initializer, the pragma is overriding this treatment because it needs to perform the addition at runtime in case it sets floating point flags.

Answer (score 2):

The `fenv_access` pragma documentation specifically states:

> The compiler disables floating-point optimizations, so your code can access the floating-point environment consistently.

Hence it looks like one of the optimisations disabled is the folding of constants, meaning that:

```
float d = 0.0 + 0.0;
```

would need to be calculated at run-time rather than compile-time. So the compiler is correct, it's not a constant in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If `#pragma fenv_access (on)` is supposed to have the same effect as `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`, then the compiler is broken with respect to the C99 and C11 standards.
However, Microsoft may not care about the C standard, and MSVC may interpret `#pragma fenv_access (on)` differently from the standard pragma.
This answer addresses whether it is allowed by the standard after `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`.

At the top level,

```
float d = 0.0 + 0.0;
```

declares an object `d` with static storage duration and initializer `0.0 + 0.0`.
The expression `0.0 + 0.0` is a constant expression.
As such, in an implementation supporting Annex F floating-point semantics (IEC 60559/IEEE 754), `0.0 + 0.0` here is to be evaluated (as if) at translation time with no effect on the floating-point environment at execution time.

C11, §F.8.4 Constant expressions, ¶1 (emphasis added):

> An arithmetic constant expression of floating type, *other than one in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration*, is evaluated (as if) during execution…
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> ```
> #include <fenv.h>
> #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
> void f(void)
> {
>   float w[] = { 0.0/0.0 };    // raise an exception
>   static float x = 0.0/0.0;   // does not raise an exception
> ...
> ```

C11, §F.8.5 Initialization, ¶1:

> …All computation for initialization of objects that have static or thread storage duration is done (as if) at translation time.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> ```
> #include <fenv.h>
> #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
> void f(void)
> {
>   float u[] = { 1.1e75 };    // raises exceptions
>   static float v = 1.1e75;   // does not raise exceptions
> ...
> ```

The examples demonstrate that constant expressions involving floating-point arithmetic are allowed in initializers for objects with static storage duration even if FENV_ACCESS is turned on.

Comment: Even if Microsoft claims that their C compiler is C99 or C11 compliant (which is far from actual state of things: only C90 compliance is claimed), then the compiler is _not broken_ because the definition of the `#pragma` (C11, 6.10.6) includes _... causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner_. I guess that the need of deviation from standard behavior was the reason of introducing their own pragma `#pragma fenv_access` instead of using the standard pragma `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`.

Comment: By the way, C90 does not mention `#pragma STDC`. In C90 any `#pragma` _causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner_.

Comment: Correct, they are absolutely within their rights to interpret `#pragma fenv_access (on)` differently from `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` under the standard—confusing as that may be.  That's why my answer is premised on the hypothesis that they are intended to mean the same thing (which may or may not be true); this Q&A page already comes up in web search results for queries like “pragma fenv_access float constant” so I thought it would be helpful additional information.